# Api facebook permissions

Tags: facebook, user-permissions

I have a problem with my web application. I need to get any permissions from the user, user_photos, publish_actions...
To get this, I redirect the user to this url:

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=(..)scope=publish_actions%2Cuser_photos%2Cmanage_pages%2Cpublish_pages

When I am log in with my developer user, it works fine, but, when I log in with another user, I only get public permissions...

¿Why?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to pass the Login Review process for publically using of extended permissions. It's all in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review